# Render HTML and take screenshot/thumbnail

Tags: c#, html

As part of an application I am developing, a user can create document templates using HTML (or  rather, a web based rich text editor that uses HTML). When the user then saves their template, I want to be able to render this HTML 'in memory' and grab a thumbnail sized screenshot of the output, so the user can see their template looks in a thumbnail.

Is this possible in C#?

Comment: Try [PhantomJS](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture)